# How to print text from textarea?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, printing

I want to print text from text area.

I have a textarea which text can be updated by user. When user update text from textarea and then print the updated text can be print on page. And this text can be print on print page without textarea.

Please suggest any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think I got what you are asking for. Give it a try:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Print TextArea</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function printTextArea() {
        childWindow = window.open('','childWindow','location=yes, menubar=yes, toolbar=yes');
        childWindow.document.open();
        childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body>');
        childWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('targetTextArea').value.replace(/\n/gi,'<br>'));
        childWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        childWindow.print();
        childWindow.document.close();
        childWindow.close();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="targetTextArea">
      TextArea value...
    </textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="printTextArea()" value="Print Text"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically this will open another child window and execute javascript print on that so that the textarea and other things don't get printed.

Comment: Btw, added another tag 'javascript' to your question.