# Only Print Multiple Textareas

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a page so that users can enter in text with the intent to print out. I'm going off of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732795/how-to-print-text-from-textarea) that does exactly what I'm trying to do, except in my version there will be multiple textareas.

Is there a way to do this? I have 0% JS knowledge, but I feel like there has to be a way to cycle (loop?) through each textarea. Also, I'm wondering if it'll print overflow text.

I've tried changing the ID to a class and then updating to 'getElementsbyClassName' but that seemed to break everything.

Also open to other solutions as well...

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Print TextArea</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printTextArea() {
            childWindow = window.open('', 'childWindow', 'location=yes, menubar=yes, toolbar=yes');
            childWindow.document.open();
            childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body>');
            childWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('targetTextArea').value.replace(/\n/gi, '<br>'));
            childWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            childWindow.print();
            childWindow.document.close();
            childWindow.close();
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="targetTextArea">
      TextArea value...
    </textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="printTextArea()" value="Print Text" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code below; it now does what you want it to do.  Changes I made:

1. `document.querySelectorAll('textarea')` now selects all `<textarea>` elements on the page. (Your code previously would have selected a maximum of one.) You could also give each `<textarea>` a `class="printableTextarea"` attribute (or whatever you want to call the attribute) and then select all of them with `document.querySelectorAll('.printableTextarea')` instead. That wpuld be the better way to handle this; what if you have a group of textareas you want to print, but then, somewhere else on the page, a standalone textarea which served some other purpose and shouldn't be included in the printout? Assuming that standalone textarea didn't have a `class="printableTextarea"` attribute, you would exclude that textarea, which is what you'd want to do.
2. I added a second `<textarea>` to your code so we could actually test whether the multiple-textarea logic worked.
3. I'm using `querySelectorAll()` to get all textareas on the page. There are a few ways to select multiple elements on a page (`getElementsByClassName()` is what you'd use if you took my suggestion above of giving the textareas you want to print a `printableTextarea` class, for example); this is one of them, and the simplest, for your needs.
4. I removed your `id="targetTextArea"` attribute; it's not needed here, and also, you generally don't want for more than one element to have the same `id` attribute.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Print TextArea</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function printTextArea() {
                childWindow = window.open('', 'childWindow', 'location=yes, menubar=yes, toolbar=yes');
                childWindow.document.open();
                childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body>');

                var allTextareaText = '';

                var allTextareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
                for (var i = 0, len = allTextareas.length; i < len; i++) {
                    allTextareaText += allTextareas[i].value + '\n\n';
                }
                childWindow.document.write(allTextareaText.replace(/\n/gi, '<br>'));
                childWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                childWindow.print();
                childWindow.document.close();
                childWindow.close();
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="50">
            TextArea value...
        </textarea>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="50">
            TextArea value...
        </textarea>
        <input type="button" onclick="printTextArea()" value="Print Text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does -- thank you. It doesn't seem to work in Chrome or Safari, though... https://shareable.s3.amazonaws.com/print_test.html

Comment: @DD1229 Yes, odd: works for me locally in Chrome but not at your AWS URL. My guess is that `childWindow.close();` is closing the popup window before it has a chance to print - in other words, `childWindow.print();` behaves synchronously on Chrome and Safari.  Just a guess. But removing `childWindow.close();` would give you some idea of whether that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have to print all the textarea or some specific textarea.