# window.print inclusive textarea values

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print an html page, which works wonderfully, but I am missing the values ​​within the text areas when printing?

How can I include the values ​​of the text areas?

Here is the code of the print function:

```
  function print(section) {
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=800');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Navigationlog</title>');

            //Print the Table CSS.
            var table_style = document.getElementById("table_style").innerHTML;
            printWindow.document.write('<style type = "text/css">');
            printWindow.document.write(table_style);
            printWindow.document.write('</style>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head>');
    
            //Print the DIV contents i.e. the HTML Table.
            printWindow.document.write('<body>');
            var divContents = document.getElementById(section).innerHTML;
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body>');
    
            printWindow.document.write('</html>');
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();;
  }
```

Here is the complete example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<style id="table_style" type="text/css">
  @media print {
    body {
      transform: scale(.97);
      height: fit-content;
      width: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    textarea {
      font-size: 1.0vw;
    }
    #routeTable td {
      font-size: 1.0vw;
    }
    #routeTable th {
      font-size: 1.0vw;
    }
  }
  
  html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* for Debug */
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* for Debug */
  }
  /* Style the tab content */
  
  .pagecontent {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Navlog */
  

  tr {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 0.5vw;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vw;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  th {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 0.5vw;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vw;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  td {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0.3vw;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  #left {
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, #357987, #357987 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%, transparent);
  }
  
  #right {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #357987, #357987 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%, transparent);
  }
  
  table {
    width: 100% !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
  }
  
  textarea {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 2vw;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  #routeTable td {
    border: 0.2vw solid black;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  
  #routeTable th {
    border: 0.2vw solid black;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #routeTable tr {
    border: 0.2vw solid black;
  }
  
  #routeTable table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 0.2vw;
    margin-block-end: 0.2vw;
    margin-inline-start: 0vw;
    margin-inline-end: 0vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 0.5vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    color: black;
  }
  
  #toolbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #035869;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    padding: 0.5vh 0;
  }
  
  #document_controls {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0.5vh 0;
    padding-left: 1vh;
  }
  
  #save,
  #print,
  #previous,
  #next {
    font-size: large;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-color: #357987;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15vw;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin: 0 0.5vh;
  }
  
  #save:hover,
  #print:hover,
  #previous:hover,
  #next:hover {
    font-size: larger;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div id="toolbar" class="noprint">
    <div id="document_controls">
      <button id="print" onclick="printPage()">Print</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Navlog" class="pagecontent" style="padding-bottom: 1cm;">
    <section id="pageNavlog">
      <table id="routeTable" style="margin-top: 1vw;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="background-color: #035869; font-size: 2vw;" colspan="17">Navigationlog</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table id="routeTable" style="border: none; margin-top: -0.2vw;">
        <tbody style="border: none;">
          <tr>
            <td style="background-color: #357987; width: 15%" colspan="3">Aircraft Registration:</td>
            <td colspan="3"><textarea  style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left; margin-left: 0.5vw; padding-top: 0.21em;"></textarea></td>
            <td style="background-color: #357987; width: 15%" colspan="2">Date:</td>
            <td colspan="3"><textarea style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left; margin-left: 0.5vw; padding-top: 0.21em;"></textarea></td>
            <td style="background-color: #357987; width: 15%" colspan="3">Pilot in command:</td>
            <td colspan="4"><textarea style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left; margin-left: 0.5vw; padding-top: 0.21em;"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

<script>

  var openNavlog = openPage('Navlog');


  function openPage(page) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, pagecontent;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    pagecontent = document.getElementsByClassName("pagecontent");
    for (i = 0; i < pagecontent.length; i++) {
      pagecontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(page).style.display = "block";
  }


  function printPage() {
    print('pageNavlog');
  }

  function print(section) {
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=800');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Navigationlog</title>');

            //Print the Table CSS.
            var table_style = document.getElementById("table_style").innerHTML;
            printWindow.document.write('<style type = "text/css">');
            printWindow.document.write(table_style);
            printWindow.document.write('</style>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head>');
    
            //Print the DIV contents i.e. the HTML Table.
            printWindow.document.write('<body>');
            var divContents = document.getElementById(section).innerHTML;
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body>');
    
            printWindow.document.write('</html>');
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();;
  }
  
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print text from textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732795/how-to-print-text-from-textarea)

Comment: No, this prints only the textareas?! but i like to print the innerHTML from div with the textarea values inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just giving a point, you are just selecting all innerHTML but not the values. So one of the easiest way is to just save the `textarea` values and assign it back while printing in a `printWindow`.

I just added the above words in programming sentence in the below code.

```
function print(section) {
       var textArea1 = document.getElementById('1').value;
       var textArea2 = document.getElementById('2').value;
       var textArea3 = document.getElementById('3').value;
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Navigationlog</title>');

                //Print the Table CSS.
                var table_style = document.getElementById("table_style").innerHTML;
                printWindow.document.write('<style type = "text/css">');
                printWindow.document.write(table_style);
                printWindow.document.write('</style>');
                printWindow.document.write('</head>');
        
                //Print the DIV contents i.e. the HTML Table.
                printWindow.document.write('<body>');
                var divContents = document.getElementById(section).innerHTML;
                printWindow.document.write(divContents);
                printWindow.document.write('</body>');
        
                printWindow.document.write('</html>');
                printWindow.document.getElementById('1').value = textArea1;
                printWindow.document.getElementById('2').value = textArea2;
                printWindow.document.getElementById('3').value = textArea3;
                printWindow.print();
                printWindow.close();
      }
```

I think it's not the best way. But it works very fine.